# Excel VB - getelementsbytagname - returns Run-time error '438'

Tags: excel, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, vba

I'm a golfing enthusiast and a hobby programmer. I am attempting to write VB code that will grab a handicap from a website if passed a specific value (membership number). I have used a piece of code I found that appears to work well for their particular application, but the website I need to use appears to be slightly more complex.

An excerpt of the webpage structure looks like the following:

```
<div id="exactHandicap">
   <h3>G.A. Handicap</h3>
   <div id="handicapType">
       (Men's)
   </div>
   <br>
   <span>
       <span id="ContentPage_lblExactHandicap">26.9</span></span>
   <span id="AnchoredPanel">
   </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to simply grab the **26.9** value

I've been searching for days as to how to reference it correctly with getelementsbytagname or getelementbyId but each return an error, the lastest being error '438'

I am a HTML novice and this project has clearly identified that, but I'm sure that someone in this community has the answer.

My code (borrowed from an online tutorial) is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Row = Range("GolfLinkNumber").Row And _
  Target.Column = Range("GolfLinkNumber").Column Then
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://handicap.golflink.com.au/handicaphistory.asp?framed=1&golflink_No=" & Range("GolfLinkNumber").Value
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.Document

    Dim HandicapValue As String

    HandicapValue = Doc.getElementByTagName("ContentPage_lblExactHandicap").innervalue
    MsgBox HandicapValue

  End If

End Sub
```

The error is at the...

*HandicapValue = Doc.getElementByTagName("ContentPage_lblExactHandicap").innervalue*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may well need `getElementByID`. `getElementByTagName` is looking for the `span` tag. If that does not work, do you have some actual numbers for testing purposes?

Comment: Not sure of how to use those functions together. Here are some testing numbers:

Comment: 4011212827, 4011215174

Comment: HandicapValue = Doc.getElementById("ContentPage_lblExactHandicap").innerHTML

Comment: Yep thats the one. The Tagname for that is `span` and the ID is `ContentPage_lblExactHandicap` so thats why it needs to be ID and not Tagname. Good to know it worked!